# Soap Service Not Working on 7070 port in Zimbra Collaboration

Tags: zimbra, zimlet, zimbra-talk

Currently i am working on Zimbra Collaboration project . All services are working except postfix , not access 7070 port services

[image: enter image description]

Comment: please avoid posting images of text...